# Should authors disclose that they are a writer of one of the methods in a benchmarking paper?

Tags: publications

I read a paper written by two authors which benchmarked various methods to analyse genetic data. The authors concluded that method X was the best in terms of sensitivity and precision.

I later realised that both of the authors writing the benchmark paper were also on the original paper for method X, which had three authors in total. The authors did not explicitly state they were authors of method X, but the paper from method X was cited with the author names visible.

Is it generally expected that authors should make this clear to readers of the paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such things should be noted to avoid claims of a conflict of interest. It seems that, in the current case, sufficient notice was given even if not stated explicitly (the citation).

But if you create something (a method, say) and then claim that it is "best", people should know the details. The authors aren't exactly disinterested in the results and it may take additional scrutiny to be assured of the outcomes.